# Installed Steam via terminal, but not marked as "installed" in Ubuntu Software Center. How to fix it?

Tags: apt, software-center, steam

I installed steam using *sudo apt-get install steam*, because there are two Steam programs in Ubuntu Software Center and I didn'd know which one is good. Now I found out that Steam is not seen by USC as installed. I want to fix it by reinstalling Steam using USC. Is using *sudo apt-get remove steam* enough or some dependencies won't be removed?

Comment: `sudo apt-get remove` is enough, however after you run that you may need to run `sudo apt-get autoremove` to get rid of dependencies that are no longer needed. But only if apt-get tells you so when you run the first command.

Answer (score 0):

I would run these commands:

```
sudo apt-get remove steam
```

(to remove steam itself)

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

(to remove the dependancies)

```
sudo apt-get purge steam
```

(if you want to purge the config files and such)